# Constructing parameter groups in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

In the `torch.optim` [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html), it is stated that model parameters can be grouped and optimized with different optimization hyperparameters. It says that

> For example, this is very useful when one wants to specify per-layer
> learning rates:
>
> ```
> optim.SGD([
>                 {'params': model.base.parameters()},
>                 {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}
>             ], lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
> ```
>
> This means that `model.base`’s parameters will use the default
> learning rate of `1e-2`, `model.classifier`’s parameters will use a
> learning rate of `1e-3`, and a momentum of `0.9` will be used for all
> parameters.

I was wondering how to define such groups that have `parameters()` attribute. What came to my mind was something in the form of

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.base()
        self.classifier()

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def base(self):
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 264)

    def classifier(self):
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(264, 128)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 964)

    def forward(self, y0):

        y1 = self.relu(self.fc1(y0))
        y2 = self.relu(self.fc2(y1))
        y3 = self.relu(self.fc3(y2))

        return self.fc4(y3)
```

How should I modify the snippet above to be able to get `model.base.parameters()`? Is the only way to define a `nn.ParameterList` and explicitly add `weight`s and `bias`es of the desired layers to that list? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will show three approaches to solving this. In the end though, it comes down to personal preference.

---

##### - Grouping parameters with [`nn.ModuleDict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleDict.html).

I noticed here an answer using `nn.Sequential` to group the layers which allow to
target different sections of the model using the `parameters` attribute of `nn.Sequential`. Indeed `base` and classifier might be more than sequential layers. I believe a more general approach is to leave the module as is, but instead, initialize an additional `nn.ModuleDict` module which will contain all parameters ordered by the optimization group in separate [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html)s:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 264)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(264, 128)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 964)

        self.params = nn.ModuleDict({
            'base': nn.ModuleList([self.fc1, self.fc2]),
            'classifier': nn.ModuleList([self.fc3, self.fc4])})

    def forward(self, y0):
        y1 = self.relu(self.fc1(y0))
        y2 = self.relu(self.fc2(y1))
        y3 = self.relu(self.fc3(y2))
        return self.fc4(y3)
```

Then you can define your optimizer with:

```
optim.SGD([
    {'params': model.params.base.parameters()},
    {'params': model.params.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}
], lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```

*Do note `MyModel`'s `parameters`' generator **won't** contain duplicate parameters.*

---

##### - Creating an interface for accessing parameter groups.

A different solution is to provide an interface in the `nn.Module` to separate the parameters into groups:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 264)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(264, 128)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 964)

    def forward(self, y0):
        y1 = self.relu(self.fc1(y0))
        y2 = self.relu(self.fc2(y1))
        y3 = self.relu(self.fc3(y2))
        return self.fc4(y3)

    def base_params(self):
        return chain(m.parameters() for m in [self.fc1, self.fc2])

    def classifier_params(self):
        return chain(m.parameters() for m in [self.fc3, self.fc4])
```

*Having imported [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as `chain`.*

Then define your optimizer with:

```
optim.SGD([
    {'params': model.base_params()},
    {'params': model.classifier_params(), 'lr': 1e-3}
], lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```

---

##### - Using child `nn.Module`s.

Lastly, you can define your module sections as submodules (here it comes down as the method as the `nn.Sequential` one, yet you can generalize this to any submodules).

```
class Base(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(nn.Linear(1, 512),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(512, 264),
                         nn.ReLU())

class Classifier(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(nn.Linear(264, 128),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(128, 964))

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.base = Base()
        self.classifier = Classifier()

    def forward(self, y0):
        features = self.base(y0)
        out = self.classifier(features)
        return out
```

Here again you can use the same interface as the first method:

```
optim.SGD([
    {'params': model.base.parameters()},
    {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}
], lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```

I would argue this is the best practice. However, it forces you to define each of your components into separate `nn.Module`, which can be a hassle when experimenting with more complex models.

Comment: Are you able to run the first method? `OrderedDict` seems to be an attribute of `collections`, not `torch.nn`. Then, how does model have attributes `base` and `classifier`?

Comment: @Blade Indeed, sorry for the confusion. in the first method `model.params` is a `collections.OrderedDict` and should be accessed via strings, not attributes. Thank you for taking the time to edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you! In case I also have a `nn.Parameter` that want to add to one item in the dictionary, what would be the minimal edit needed on the first method? e.g. how should I edit `'base': nn.ModuleList([self.fc1, self.fc2])` to include the new `nn.Parameter`?

Comment: Let me add that my own solution would be to change the `nn.ModuleList` to `nn.ParameterList` and add `.weight` and `.bias` for each layer. Can this been done more efficiently/cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`torch.nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) to define `base` and `classifier`. Your class definition can then be:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.base = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 512), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(512,264), nn.ReLU())
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(264,128), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(128,964))

    def forward(self, y0):
        return self.classifier(self.base(y0))
```

Then, you can access parameters using `model.base.parameters()` and `model.classifier.parameters()`.